# scroll property on body element set to no

Tags: master-page

In Randy Disgrills starter masterpage the body element has scroll="no", why must it have this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body scroll=”no” onload=”…” class=”v4master”>
```

The two important parts of the tag are the “scroll” and “class” attributes. The “scroll” attribute is used to force IE to hide the page scrollbar. Since SharePoint handles the scrollbar independently, we need to stop the browser from interfering. For other browsers, the scrollbar is hidden using CSS styles which are explained later in this post. The CSS class applied to the “body” tag is used to apply CSS styles in the corev4.css stylesheet which are part of the Ribbon posITioning system. If you are using a custom stylesheet, you may leave this out; but make sure to apply the needed CSS styles in some other way (perhaps by referencing “body” directly in your stylesheet).

Source Link [MasterPageIssues](http://sharepoint-2010.appspot.com/2010/04/16/Customizing-Ribbon-Positioning-in-SharePoint-2010-Master-Pages.html)

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
The thing is that since we have one of the first versions of the starter masterpage (2009) we don't even have the v4master class although things seem to work. And for anonymous users we don't even include the core.css, still works. And I could not see any CSS properties when inspecting the body element that would remove the scroll bar. And the scroll="no" seems to only do anything in IE6, as well as it's not a valid attribute on the body element for our doctype

Comment: Are you getting any error while removing this tag?

Comment: Not that I have seen, that is why I asked. If I could get a concrete error I would know what to look for, but with no error it could affect any random feature.

Comment: I would suggest to keep that as it is. Or try removing it and check out if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Think I will try running without it for a while and see. We don't want to have it, for instance because as I said it breaks with our doctype. Thanks for help